# Contact Form auto save when typing in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have 2 forms, both of them are divided in 2.

First time I ask for **name**, **email**, **phone** and **company** than I have 2 buttons **continue** and **call me**

Some of them may not click continue button so I need to get this details before they run away from the page.

I need the form to do an auto save when all fields are completed even if user is not submitting the form.

How can I do this with contact form 7 or formidable forms?
I'm open to new suggestions too, other plugins etc..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this plugin contact form 7 AutoSaver  ,
 Select some forms to enable auto-save on them, meaning when a user fill the form, without even submitting it, then navigates to another page and comes back or refreshes the page, they will see the data they previously filled still available for them!

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-autosaver/
```

Comment: I use this, but this for is saving the details for user in browser not for me